# Avro Rust unsupported union of null and fixed

Tags: rust, schema, union, avro, fixed

I have an avro created by a Java code. I am trying to read this with Rust reader and getting this error

`` Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: DeserializeValue("unsupported union: Union(1, Fixed(4, [192, 168, 1, 2]))")' ``

It seems that union of "null" and "fixed" is not implemented yet.

The code in Rust:

```
    let bytes = read(path).unwrap();

    let schema_str = read_to_string("sw.schema.avsc").unwrap();
    let schema = Schema::parse_str(&*schema_str).unwrap();

    let reader = Reader::with_schema(&schema, &*bytes).unwrap();
    println!(">>> {}", schema.canonical_form());

    for record in reader {
        let r = record.unwrap();

        // it fails here on parsing data 
        let record: Flow = apache_avro::from_value::<Flow>(&r).unwrap();
        println!("{:?}", record);
    }
```

related schema definition for the field

```
             "name": "ip",
              "type": [
                "null",
                {
                  "type": "fixed",
                  "name": "IPv4",
                  "size": 4
                },
                {
                  "type": "fixed",
                  "name": "IPv6",
                  "size": 16
                }
              ],
              "default": null
```

Is it something I can parse somehow else or just report this as a Apache Avro Rust code bug?